# How to make rename indexes re-runnable?

Tags: oracle, plsql, partitioning

The scenario goes like this.

I created a partitioned table `A` with two indexes. Then inserted records from original table `B` which also has two indexes. Table `B` has 133 million rows.

Now I would like to rename old table B as '_old' including its indexes,
Finally, rename new partitioned table back to original table including its indexes.

I know i can simply write Alter statements to do the above tasks but the idea is to make it **re-runnable**! How can I do that?

```
DECLARE
   PROCEDURE check_indexes
   (
      table_owner_in    IN VARCHAR2
     ,table_name_in     IN VARCHAR2
     ,index_name_in     IN VARCHAR2
     ,new_index_name_in VARCHAR2
   ) IS
      count_indexes NUMBER;
   BEGIN

      SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO count_indexes
        FROM user_indexes
       WHERE table_owner = table_owner_in
         AND table_name = table_name_in
         AND index_name = index_name_in;

      IF count_indexes > 0
      THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('ALTER INDEX ' || index_name_in ||
                              ' RENAME TO ' || new_index_name_in);
      END IF;
   END;
BEGIN
   check_indexes(table_owner_in    => 'UTILS_OWNER'
                ,table_name_in     => 'OP_LOG_OLD'
                ,index_name_in     => 'OL_MODULE_NAME_I'
                ,new_index_name_in => 'OL_MODULE_NAME_I_OLD');

   check_indexes(table_owner_in    => 'UTILS_OWNER'
                ,table_name_in     => 'OP_LOG_OLD'
                ,index_name_in     => 'OL_PK'
                ,new_index_name_in => 'OL_PK_OLD');

   check_indexes(table_owner_in    => 'UTILS_OWNER'
                ,table_name_in     => 'OP_LOG'
                ,index_name_in     => 'OL_MODULE_NAME_I_NEW'
                ,new_index_name_in => 'OL_MODULE_NAME_I');

   check_indexes(table_owner_in    => 'UTILS_OWNER'
                ,table_name_in     => 'OP_LOG'
                ,index_name_in     => 'OL_PK_NEW'
                ,new_index_name_in => 'OL_PK');
END;
```

Comment: If you want to partition a table online you should take a look to DBMS_REDEFINITION: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/online-table-redefinition-enhancements-11gr1

Comment: What do you understand as *re-runnable*? You cant twice rename `A`  to `B`... If you are on 12.2 check the [Converting a Non-Partitioned Table to a Partitioned Table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5) you need not rename nothing here,,,

Comment: @MarmiteBomber im on 12.1 so cant do the conversion. I just want to make my alter statements of renaming indexes re-runnable for original table.

Comment: You still haven't said what you actually mean by 're-runnable'. Why would you want to do this more than once? Or do you want it to be restartable after an error? Or something else?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, i would like to run this script more than once. Please have a look at my updated question above and let me know if im doing this correctly ?